# ResourcesNotFoundException when binding Int to a TextView

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

Binding an `Int` value to a `TextView` causes a `Resources$NotFoundException` with message "String resource ID #0x2a" (where `0x2a` is the value of the `Int`). Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Sample code:
* layout/activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
            <variable name="data" type="com.example.Thing" />
        </data>

        <LinearLayout tools:context=".MainActivity">
            <TextView android:text="@{data.x}"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

- Thing.kt:

  ```
  package com.example

  data class Thing(
      var x:Int = 42
  )
  ```
- MainActivity.kt:

  ```
  package com.example

  import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
  import com.example.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          var activityMain:ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
          activityMain.data = Thing()
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: You cannot call `setText()` with an arbitrary integer value. That `setText()` overload expects the `int` to be a string resource ID. You would need to convert your value to a `String` first.

Comment: Another match for an original question: '[Data Binding : Resources$NotFoundException when attribute of object is int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32837455/90527)". It's that `Resources$NotFoundException` that makes searching difficult. This duplicate will hopefully make finding the originals easier.

Comment: Added it to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`TextView.setText(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)), which was created before data binding was added to Android, interprets its argument as a resource identifier. To bind an integer to a TextView, convert the value with [`Integer.toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)) or [`String.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) ([`Int.toString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-string.html) apparently isn't available, as the value is unboxed):

```
    <TextView android:text="@{Integer.toString(data.x)}"/>
```

If `TextView.setText(int)` didn't exist, you could also write a [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) to automatically convert between the bound value type and the type the `View` displays.